# Is the matrix exponential operator convex in the domain of Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite, matrix-exponential

I know that the matrix exponential operator is not convex, but is it convex in the domain of Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices?

Comment: According to Problem V.5.1 from Bhatia's Matrix Analysis, exp is not operator convex on any interval